# Show an Alert Builder from a non-activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an alert dialog with my application from a non-activity.

So the hard thing here is that I want to do it not in an activity but in my general application class.

```
public class AppName extends com.github.droidfu.DroidFuApplication {
    public static long TIME_CONTENT_UPDATE = 60;  //half hour

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();   
        intent = new Intent(this, VSSyncController.class);
        setupTimer();

    }


    private void setupCatalogTimer() {
        final Context con = this;

        //A handler runs on a separate thread
        mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

             public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

                 showMyAlertDialog(con)
                 mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, TIME_CONTENT_UPDATE);
                 return true;
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Basically I want to show an alert dialog from there, but I need to have a way to figure out which and IF there is any activity in the foreground, so I can call it from there.

How can I possible do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your use case makes much sense.  what are you trying to accomplish by showing a dialog from the application?  Perhaps you should be using a notification instead?

Comment: Because I want to user to give an answer through that dialog (yes/no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking out of the box what I did was send a notification (when the dialog was suppose to pop) that takes the user back to the activity and there it shows the dialog!

This way we don't deal with the problem to check which activity is not in front.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of this yourself via `onPause()` and `onResume()` in each of your activities. There is nothing built in that provides this data to you.

Comment: Would it be a good idea setting a method in that AppName class like setAppCon and in each activity onCreate()/onResume() I'll set the context and onPause I'll set it to null

Comment: @alaxid: IMHO, the "good idea" is for an `Application` to not be displaying a dialog. With respect to your comment, I am not a fan of putting `Activity` objects in static context, due to the potential for memory leaks. Done properly, what you describe should be safe, though.

Comment: Not being able to do it.. Basically I want to ask the user (when the application is running in the background/foreground) if he gives permission a certain task and I can't find a way to do it. I tried this implementation but it fails even with the context.